# Set monthly recurring job dynamically with resque-schedular

Tags: resque, resque-scheduler

Banging my head against the wall with this one. Trying to dynamically add jobs with resque-scheduler. What's the syntax for creating a monthly job? For example, the code below will set up a job to run every minute.

```
config[:class] = "job_name"
config[:args] = "arg"
config[:every] = "1m"
config[:persist] = true
```

What would the syntax here be for every month? Would it be config[:every] = "1 month"? I can't seem to find any answers on the resque-scheduler docs for this.

Thanks.

Comment: have also tried '1 month', resque could not parse it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For dynamic schedules resque-scheduler uses [rufus-scheduler](https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler), as it is explained on the [documentation](https://github.com/resque/resque-scheduler#dynamic-schedules), which handles not only the actual scheduling business but also the parse of the `:every` option.

You can see that when resque-scheduler [runs](https://github.com/resque/resque-scheduler/blob/af00fdc4c56570d847f125a43958dd2bee39c66c/lib/resque/scheduler.rb#L41-L47) it basically loads all schedule information from redis and then [passes on to rufus](https://github.com/resque/resque-scheduler/blob/af00fdc4c56570d847f125a43958dd2bee39c66c/lib/resque/scheduler.rb#L131-L136).

The supported letter/durations are documented on rufus [here](https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler/blob/f4a2fdeeb62ec83db9221ae5688eb6a9b0b86f57/lib/rufus/scheduler/util.rb#L122-L148) as a map between letters and durations in seconds and you can see more complex rules on the [specs for duration parsing](https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler/blob/master/spec/parse_spec.rb#L136-L159).

For one month, you can use `1M` or you can also use `4w`, there's also `30d`...